# ASF = Multimammate?

Tags: feeding, snakes

I bought a small multi for my royal python, as part of a bundle of "let's try her on various things to see which ones she prefers". So far so good, the small mice and rat pups have all gone down a treat over the past few weeks, and she's just eaten the multi nicely.

I went over to my [iHerp](http://iherp.com/) profile to log it, and the options available included

- ASF - Adult
- ASF - Fuzzie
- ASF - Hopper
- ASF - Jumbo
- ASF - Pinks

Google tells me that ASF is an abbreviation for African Soft Furred rodent, which *describes* what a multimammate is, but are they the same thing?

And if so, then which size on iHerp will correspond to what I bought as a "small" one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my local reptile shop:

> Yep. ASF is a multimammate.

He went on to describe the sizes which he stocks:

- Pinkies - a little bigger than a normal pinkie mouse
- Small - about the size of a medium to large mouse
- Large - similar to a small weaner rat
- A fully grown and pregnant female would equate to a large weaner rat.